# Docker EPERM error when trying to build angular app in container

Tags: angular, docker, npm, docker-compose

I'm trying to containerize our current stack using docker & docker compose. Here is the docker compose file (simplified, I just kept the relevant services):

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  #FO
  angularproject:
    container_name: angularproject
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./bootstrap/front/Dockerfile
      args:
        project: angularproject
    command: npm run build:test:watch
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    volumes:
      - ./angularproject/:/var/www/html/angularproject
    expose: 
      - 4200
    restart: always
    networks:
      - traefik-public
    labels:
      traefik.enable: true
      traefik.http.routers.angularproject.rule: (Host(`vws.dev`) && PathPrefix(`/angularproject`))
      traefik.http.services.angularproject.loadbalancer.server.port: 4200

  #UTILITY
  reverse-proxy:
    container_name: traefik
    image: traefik:v2.5
    command: --api.insecure=true --providers.docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"
    networks:
      - traefik-public

networks:
  traefik-public:
```

the Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:16-buster-slim
ARG project

# set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www/html/

#install qit, openssh, libpq
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-client
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install git
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install libpq-dev

#ssh keyscan (we need it because there is git links in package.json)
RUN mkdir -p -m 0700 ~/.ssh
RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN mkdir /var/www/html/$project
RUN chmod 777 /var/www/html/$project
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash vws
USER vws

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY --chown=vws ./$project /var/www/html/$project
WORKDIR /var/www/html/$project
RUN rm -rf node_modules
EXPOSE 4200
RUN --mount=type=ssh npm i
# this is needed since we need build-angular dep
RUN --mount=type=ssh npm i --only=dev
```

The build seems to work fine, but when I try to execute the "up" command (which just runs `npm run build:test:watch`), I have the following error:

```
angularproject  | Error: Error on worker #1: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, copyfile '/var/www/html/angularproject/node_modules/@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/dist/leaflet/layers/control/leaflet-control-layers.wrapper.js' -> '/var/www/html/angularproject/node_modules/@asymmetrik/ngx-leaflet/__ivy_ngcc__/dist/leaflet/layers/control/leaflet-control-layers.wrapper.js'
```

So it looks like a permission error and that my user `vws` or npm can not write in the node modules. As you can see in the Dockerfile, I really tried to give permissions and not install everything as root. Can someone explain if I'm doing something incorrect in the process ?

Answer (score 0):

So apparently this was due to the volume set on the root of the angularproject. I did so to ensure the hot reload would work on every file of the project. however, replacing

```
    volumes:
      - ./angularproject/:/var/www/html/angularproject
```

by:

```
    volumes:
      - ./angularproject/src/:/var/www/html/angularproject/src/
```

seems to correct my issue. The hot relooad will only be performed on the src/ folder, but it is fine in my case